# Inline css value in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How would I get a css property inside javascript!

ex :

```
  <style>
     #body{
        background:red;
      }
  </style>

    <script>
       function valid(form){
          alert('enter');
          var test = document.getElementById('body').style.background ;
          alert(test');
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body id="body">
```

On alert I am not able to get the background color!

Comment: this might help http://www.wpdfd.com/forums/wpdfd/scripting/retrieving_css_values_via_javascript/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `style` property on elements only reflects the style information in the element itself (such as via the `style` attribute in the markup), not anything applied by style rules. To get those, you'd need [`getComputedStyle`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle):

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
display("foo's background color is: " +
      window.getComputedStyle(foo, null).getPropertyValue('background-color'));
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/unofa5)

---

**Off-topic**: Some of this stuff is made easier by libraries such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

Comment: i am getting in rgb how to get in hexadecimal ?

Comment: how to change existing value via javascript ?

Comment: @Ani: *"...in rgb how to get in hexadecimal"* I'm afraid you'll have to parse it, and be aware that the format may be slightly different from browser to browser. *"how to change existing value"* You can change the value for the *element* by assigning to properties of its `style` object. To change the style rule itself, you have to navigate the `styleSheets` list and work through the style rules, which is rather more complicated. Some links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.styleSheets \* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531200(v=vs.85).aspx